# I can not get Updates to work at all. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. This is also affecting downloading and installing applications?

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, updates, update-manager

```
sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Err:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease

  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.ZpYFOA for passing config to apt-key
Ign:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Err:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release 
               
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/au.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-updates_Release - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:5 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports Release

  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/au.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-backports_Release - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release

  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-security_Release - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Reading package lists... Done
```

Oh and It not letting me install any applications or printer drivers to!

Comment: Please read the info on this site https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can always edit your post. Please provide supporting information in your question, and not as comments. Thanks!

Comment: Please list the output of this command: `grep "[[:space:]]ro[[:space:],]" /proc/mounts ` (to see if your filesystem is read-only).

Comment: `Read-only file system'  seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is clearly stated right there in your output: `(30: Read-only file system)`

A read-only file system cannot save (or otherwise *write*). This kind of event typically occurs due to a disk error -- a hardware error, not software bug, not human mistake.

- Most users can simply reboot. For most users, this will re-mount your disk read/write, and your system will work properly again.
- Some users, if there is a problem during reboot, must run `fsck` on the affected partition to clean up corruption that occurred during the disk error.
- Disk errors occurring more and more frequently are a classic symptom of dying storage hardware. Run a SMART test to confirm the problem. If dying, your storage device might take your (unrecoverable) data with it, so backup your data to good hardware and replace the unreliable hardware immediately.